# Mobile App Speech to Text Save Raw Audio file in SpeechRecognizer

Tags: java, android

how to save the raw audio file in SpeechRecognizer Android Java?
i already use mediarecorder but there is a conflict using mediarecorder and speechrecognizer

i think for speechrecognizer not working if the mediarecorder is use

my code:

```
speechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {           
        imgView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == motionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    stopRecording();
                    speechRecognizer.stopListening();
                }
                if(motionEvent.getAction() == motionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_mic_none_24);
                    startRecording();
                    speechRecognizer.startListening(speechIntent);
                }
                return  false;
            }
        });

        disableTextFields(editText);
    }

    // Method to start recording
    private void startRecording() {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        String downloadFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(downloadFolderPath + "/your_audio_file.3gp");
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mediaRecorder.start();
    }

    // Method to stop recording
    private void stopRecording() {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            mediaRecorder = null;
        }
    }
```

save the raw audio file in SpeechRecognizer